# Is there any diprotoic acid where both pka's are less than 0?

Tags: acid-base

The question states it all.

I'm working out special cases for a different problem and such an acid would create another special case.

Sulfuric Acid is the strongest that I remember. pKa's −3, 1.99

Comment: I guess any disulfonic acid with sufficiently long organic link in the middle will do.

Comment: @IvanNeretin - Super fantastic! Thank you.

Comment: @MaxW wants superacidic MHA buffer....  :-)

Comment: @Poutnik - Yes, the idea was to find an "amphoteric" salt of such an acid, eg Sodium hydrogen 1,2-Ethanedisulfonate.

Comment: Well I did look up 1,2-Ethanedisulfonic acid which exists, and the disodium salt exists. You could perhaps make the monosodium salt by reacting the acid with NaOH and drying. Does the fluorine analog even exist?

Comment: What about $$\ce{ HO-SO2-CF2-CF2-SO2-OH}$$ :-)    ( See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triflic_acid   pKa −14.7±2.0 ).

Comment: It is an intriguingly fascinating  molecule. I'd guess that either it is unstable, or that someone, somewhere, has made it. // The question with a lot of such molecules is not "Is it useful?", but rather "Can I do it?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Ethanedisulfonic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethanedisulfonic_acid) does indeed have $pK_{a1}=-2.06, pK_{a2}=-1.46$.

Using polycyano substutution can also work.  [This paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Absorption-and-Fluorescence-Emission-Attributes-of-Zahid-Grampp/8051ea512f0de38e77396366007cddd540ec223a) reports the table below, note that the tetracyano hydroquinone "makes it" (in the excited state produced by irradiation).

[image]

Comment: The Wikipedia link for Methanedisulfonic acid is only for the monosulfonic acid. The disulfonic acid does exist, but I couldn't find any pKa values for it. However both pKa values would surely be less than 0.

Comment: Removed.  Misread something back then, I guess.